# How to detect if all edge points of a 2D sprite are touched?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to detect if the player has touched (touch input touch) all the edge points of a 2D sprite, and if so, increment a point. The shape is a 2D sprite with a polygon collider.

[image: Shape with 2D polygon collider attached]

I am also drawing a line renderer on top of the shape where the touch collides with the polygon collider. To serve as an indicator for the player.

[image: Shape with 2D polygon collider attached]

As a beginner, I have been struggling with this a lot. How can I achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## **Edit:**

Following willow's approach:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one easy way ( without so much mathematics  ) is to add Rigidbody2d/Collider2d around your circles, then you check if the player touch them in order. every small rectangle is a Rigidbody2d/Collider2d, so you raycast , if it hits, add it to an array. when touch finishes, check if all rectangles have been touches in order with a For loop 1,2,3,4,5,6. the more rigidbodies you have, the more accurate you are.

[image]

Comment: Apologies. Maybe my question was not clear enough. There is no other player sprite. The user will be touching the shape (touch input touch). And moving their fingers in a circle. I want to check if the user has completly moved their fingers around the circle surface.

Comment: Thankyou willow. I like the approach and appreciate you drawing and explaining the approach. However, I have a slight problem the shapes will change after the player completes one, so the next shape can be a triangle, rectangle, or even an open shape, like maybe the alphabet "S." How do you think I can approach this? :)

Comment: you're welcome. on that case you need to work more and do it manually for every shape, create prefabs, load the prefabs, Circle, Triangles, rectangles, line, spiral. doesn't matter which shape you have as long as you check the rigidbodies in order. even a random-directed line can be done with this method. of course there are some other ways, but they are too harder than this. this is an easy one. I suggest that you go with circle first, when you achieve that, then you will find how to do that for others , too

Comment: Thank you. That is the approach I am going for. But I ran into another slight problem. I have created these small squares (edited and added the image) and placed them on the Gameobject. The underlying game object has a Polygon Collider (for drawing the indicator), and the squares on top have a box collider. I am detecting touch using raycast and cannot detect a touch on the squares but only on the underlying shape. I can detect the touches when turning off the polygon collider but not when it is on. I would really appreciate your help with this final puzzle.

Comment: you're welcome. you need to ignore the polygon collider to be ray casted. the easiest way is to select your polygon's game object, then change the layer to "Ignore Raycast" ( from inspector) so your polygon won't be raycasted anymore.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. That did it with a few tweaks!